# iOS Certificate Expiration: Do you resubmit app?

Tags: ios

I got a notice from Apple that my certificate expires this month so I created a new one and prov. profile, but I couldn't figure out if I have to re-submit my app... so do I?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. As long as you continue paying for the developer program, your app will stay in the app store, and you can just refresh the cert and the provisioning prof when they expire before you submit your next update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit app to the AppStore, Apple resigns it. So my answer would be "No, you don't need to resubmit".